# Make a method not accessible from derived class but still public

Tags: c#, inheritance, hide, accessor

I have a `Data` class.

And a `DerivedClass : Data`.

The `Data` has the data itself and lots of methods to work with that data.

But `DerivedClass` must inherit only part of those methods, since some of them may cause bad results. (Issues that happens only to `DerivedClass` but not to `Data`)

So I wish to hide part of them (from some accessor in base class, not typing `new` to hide methods for every derived class)

Is that possible? Is there a workaround?

Comment: ...I quite know the answer after thinking a while...but maybe some enlightened workaround may come.

Comment: Why do you nee the method to be public?

Comment: Because they are user methods to work with `Data` class. Without them, class would be almost useless.

Comment: Of course, the question is why can't they be private?

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to create a base class that has only methods which can be modified by derived classes. Data class will be sealed and still remain the same and this base class will be composed by Data class. Code looks something like below:

```
public sealed class Data
{
  private object data; //actual data
  private BaseDataOperations dataOperations; //This class will implement methods

  public void Method1()  //This method is accessible to others but can't be modified
  {
    // manipulate data
  }

  public void Method2()  //This method will be polymorphically performed
  {
      dataOperations.Method2(data);
  }
}

public class BaseDataOperations
{

  public virtual void Method2(object data)  //This method will be polymorphically performed
  {
      //manipulate data
  }
}

public class DerivedDataOperations : BaseDataOperations
{

  public override void Method2(object data)  //This method will be polymorphically performed
  {
      //manipulate data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shadowing,implement the same method exactly(public,return type,name,parameters)
Then in your derived class in that method implement your new logic.

```
class Class1
    {
        public int Get()
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public Class1()
        {

        }

        public virtual void ForBoth()
        {

        }
    }

    class class2 : Class1
    {
        public class2()
        {

        }

        public override void ForBoth()
        {
            base.ForBoth();
        }

        public int Get()
        {
            return 2;
        }

    }
```

In my example the shadowed method was Get(). 
You can change other members like in the example bellow
class1 has property int MyInt,and i converted in class2 to a method

```
class Class1
    {
        public int MyInt = 0;

        public int Get()
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public Class1()
        {

        }

        public virtual void ForBoth()
        {

        }
    }

    class class2 : Class1
    {
        public class2()
        {

        }

        public override void ForBoth()
        {
            base.ForBoth();
        }

        public void MyInt(string s)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s);
        }

        public int Get()
        {
            return 2;
        }

    }
```

Apart from this you should consider create interfaces that implement
those "behaviors". check out the adapter pattern
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx